# Drools query "wildcard"

Tags: java, drools

Is it possible to insert facts into a Drools working memory (e.g. constraints on the query) that act as a wildcard?

For example, imagine I have the following rules:

```
rule "meal_exceptions_1"
    agenda-group "MEAL"
    salience 100
    when
        Meal(id = "Breakfast")
        Person(name == "Sally")
    then
        insert(new Food("Jelly"));
        drools.setFocus("OTHERGRP");
end 

rule "meal_breakfast"
    agenda-group "MEAL"
    when
        Meal(id == "Breakfast")
    then
        insert(new Food("Cornflakes"));
        drools.setFocus("OTHERGRP");
end 

rule "meal_dinner"
    agenda-group "MEAL"
    when
        Meal(id == "Dinner")
    then
        insert(new Food("Fish Fingers"));
        drools.setFocus("OTHERGRP");
end
```

I want to answer the question "what are all the possible foods that could be ordered for breakfast" (maybe I'm ordering in supplies for the kitchen).

I can easily insert a fact, `new Meal("Breakfast")` to constrain the results to just those that apply for breakfast.  However, my application has no knowledge of which people may have requested exceptions, or even what the whole set of people are.  I want to add another fact along the lines of `Person("*")`, so that this will match the first rule, even though I don't know (or care!) that it is specifically Sally who has requested a different food.

The desired output is a working memory which contains both Cornflakes and Jelly.  Is it possible to issue such a query without specific knowledge of the potential exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any such wildcard, and I somewhat doubt it's even possible at all.
I'm not gonna ask you why you insert facts from within Drools rules, you probably have some good reasons, otherwise back to the drawing board.

Since these are all exceptions, one way to handle this case would be to register all exception facts in your sessions. In this basic case you would only need to register Person("Sally") and you'd get a list of both Jelly and Cornflakes.

As an alternative you could add a flag, say `Person.wildcard` and change your LHS to something like `Person(name == "Sally" || wildcard)`, but that's a trade I doubt your willing to make since your registering the facts yourself from within the rules.